# How to serve a static content using ingress nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have one service called "workspace-service-b6" which is running on port 5000, See the below ingress file. Now I want to serve the static content on the same service (workspace-service-b6) by adding the path route.

Example:- Service is working on https://workspace-b6.dev.example.com

Now if the user adds  "/workspace/v2/ "at the end of the URL.

Like this:- https://workspace-b6.dev.example.com**/workspace/v2/** it will redirect to s3 bucket "https://s3.console/buckets/xyz/abc/build" where my static content is available.

My Ingress file :-

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: b6-ingress 
namespace: b6
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
tls:
- hosts:
- workspace-b6.dev.example.com
secretName: xyz-crt
rules:
- host: workspace-b6.dev.example.com
http:
paths:
- backend:
serviceName: workspace-service-b6
service port: 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

While it’s kind of possible, the real answer is “don’t”. The ingress system is just a proxy, set up separate pods for content.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: @me25, if I understood correctly your question you would like to use nginx based on which the nginx ingress controller works as a web server for serving static content, right ? As @coderanger already suggested it's simply a bad idea. Nginx ingress controller is not meant to serve any content by itself but rather routing all coming requests to the apropriate backend `Pods`. And what's wrong with serving the static content directly from s3 bucket ? You can define other service pointing to it and use it as your ingress path.

Comment: Found the answer , just need to add server snippet as annotation in ingress file